# Avoid to display NAN in datagrid?

Tags: c#

I can use a converter for this task, but my situation is this:

I've an object with several properties, I evaluate the double of each property and return the result of a function, the code explain better:

```
var partialFinalForecast = poisson.GetPartialFinalForecast();
        partialFinalForecast.GetType().GetProperties()
                                .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(double)).ToList()
                                .ForEach(x => x.SetValue(partialFinalForecast, Math.Round((double)x.GetValue(partialFinalForecast), 2)));
```

sometimes happen that this return `NAN`, how can I avoid this result directly on this query?

Comment: Either make sure your input does not return NAN, or don't display the result if it's NAN. If you want your query not to return this, change the query or change the input. This sounds like the manager who wanted a program never to fail...

Comment: I just asked if is possible do this in linq..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace `(double)x.GetValue(partialFinalForecast)` with `Double.IsNaN((double)x.GetValue(partialFinalForecast)) ? 0 : (double)x.GetValue(partialFinalForecast)`, but this is hardly a good approach (as mentioned by oerkelens)...